# how to get a list of impala hostnames in python

Tags: python, hostname, impala

I have been trying to find some ways to get a list of all the available `impala hostnames` in `python` by reading some impala configuration files. I don't know whether this is possible or not but I tried to look form some solution and couldn't find one.

What I want is that when we connect to a impala data node (either through executing a `impala shell` command or through `impyla` package), we provide impala `hostname` statically like:

```
conn = connect(host='123.45.67.89', port=21050, timeout=3600)
```

What I have been trying to look for is if there is some way I can read the `config files` of impala (or any other means) and could get the list of the available impala `hostnames`(local to the system) and then select one of them and connect to that host and execute the data statements.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

If you've enabled impala's webserver, you can get a list of active impala backends simply by issuing a `curl` command.

```
curl -s somehost:25000/backends | grep list-group-item | sed 's/.*>\(.*\)<.*/\1/'
```

Impala's webserver port is `25000` by default. You may need to adjust it to match your setup.